# How to access Sharepoint 2010 word automation services from remote server?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Basically i am trying to access the sharepoint server 2010 which is installed on remote machine to do some word operations. But when i am trying to connect with the remote server using SPSite(), it is throwing the below exception:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled
  Message=The Web application at "http://RemoteServer" could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.

Don't know how to connect with remote server using SPSite().

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. `SPSite` and, generally, the whole object model does not support connecting to a remote SharePoint farm. All you can do is access the *local* SharePoint farm.

Comment: But in the below URL http://www.iotap.com/Blogs/tabid/277/EntryId/122/The-Web-application-at-http-URL-to-SharePoint-could-not-be-found-alternate-access-mapping-in-wss-3-0.aspx it is mentioned that it will be achievable through certain configuration changes done at central sharepoint server.

Comment: That article is about Alternate Access Mappings — that's a completely unrelated feature of SharePoint. In case you have two disparate installations of SharePoint (two farms), connecting via the object model from one to the another is **just plain impossible** — by design. Period. There isn't any workaround.

Comment: yeah that's correct. We can access the word automation services from Sharepoint server through WCF and it is not possible through Managed Client Object model from a machine where Sharepoint server is not installed. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/12/07/what-is-the-difference-between-word-automation-and-word-automation-services.aspx